# Dataflow fusion + windows/triggers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm aware that Dataflow can modify a pipeline's execution graph through [Fusion Optimization](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization).

Do windows/triggers factor in at all to fusion optimization?

Does a streaming pipeline and/or unbounded sources (Pub/Sub) influence that behavior at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the complex operations of the Beam programming model, including evaluation of windowing/triggering and such, end up being translated to a low-level graph of (possibly stateful) `ParDo` and `GroupByKey` operations (a.k.a. Map and Reduce :) ).

E.g.

- You can think of the assigning windows (`Window.into()`) as a ParDo that takes an element and returns a list of pairs (element, window) for all windows into which the element's timestamp maps
- A `GroupByKey` by a key (or a `Combine`) in your original pipeline gets translated into a `GroupByKey` by a composite key `(user key, window)`
- Evaluation of triggers happens as a stateful `ParDo` that gets inserted immediately after any `GroupByKey` and reacts to new values arriving for a given key/window by buffering the new value and deciding whether, according to the trigger, it's already time to emit the accumulated values or not.

This is not an exact correspondence (semantics of windows is a little more complex than that), just to give you an idea.

Fusion operates on this low-level graph of `ParDo` and `GroupByKey`, collapsing some chains of `ParDo`'s into a single `ParDo`. Fusion doesn't care whether some of the `ParDo`s play a role related to windowing, or that a `GroupByKey` groups by a composite key, etc.

I believe in Dataflow Streaming runner, fusion is in practice more aggressive (it always collapses chains of `ParDo`s) than in the batch runner (that collapses only in cases where it seems beneficial according to data size estimates, based on the [FlumeJava paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35650.pdf)), but this can change as we make improvements to both runners.